# Approximation of the integral of $e^{i(t \sin x - n x)}$ for large $t$

Tags: integration, approximation, complex-integration

I was given a problem that asks me to approximate the integral
$$ \int_0^\pi e^{i(t \sin x - n x)}dx $$
for large positive real values of $t$.

Are there any approximation methods that might be applicable?
I have only learned the saddle point approximation, but it does not seem to work here, since the integrand is a unit complex number that oscillates in its direction very quickly.
I truly have no clue as to how to even start approaching this.

Since this is a homework problem (or at least part of it), subtle hints are more welcomed than solutions.
I'd like to solve it myself and then post it as an answer to this question if possible.

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Stationary phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation)

Comment: The preceding questions of your homework should give an hint.

Comment: The saddle point method can also be applied here. Making the substitution $z=e^{ix}$
$$I=\int_0^\pi e^{\frac{t}{2}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}e^{-ixn}\frac{e^{ix}}{e^{ix}}dx=-i\int_C e^{\frac{t}{2}(z-\frac{1}{z})}\frac{dz}{z^{n+1}}$$
where we integrate along the arch $|z|=1$ (counterclockwise) in the complex plane. The saddle point is $f'(z)=\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{2}(z-\frac{1}{z})=0\,\Rightarrow\, z=i;\,f''(i)=-i$, etc.